# Automatically splitting data into different worksheets in Excel, based on column values and using Excel formulas

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I basically have a list of employees in my spreadsheet that have certain data against them. What I need to do with this list is split these rows into different worksheets based on their job role so that I end up with various worksheets that contain 1 kind of job role each. I have seen this done with VBA but I don't know now to code in VBA and I'd prefer to stay away from pivot tables and filtering - I would like to try and find a way to use excel formulas to do this. Some test data just to give you an idea is this:

```
Name     |     Job Role     |     Target
Jeff     |     Hunter       |      3000
steve    |     Farmer       |      2000
tom      |     Hunter       |      5000
andy     |     Combined     |      10000
```

....from this table I need Jeff and Tom in 1 worksheet together, Steve in another worksheet and Andy in another (based on the job roles) so from this table I should end up with 3 worksheets.

One thing I did try is an if statement with a vlookup inside of it like this:

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(b2,a2:c4,2,FALSE)="Hunter",a2,"")
```

This is the closest I have got to getting what I want. This code will basically return the name of all the hunters when it is dragged down in excel but it will leave blanks which I do not want. I thought excel would have something in place to easily do something like this but obviously not. Does anybody know a way around this issue without VBA or filtering + copy&pasting?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this to work using `=INDEX(Sheet1!A1:A4,MATCH("Hunter",Sheet1!B1:B4,0))` on sheet 2 (without any of the column headers that you have used). The downside was that if the formula occured more times that names, its started to repeat names, but i think that hta can be addressed with an `=IF()` and `=COUNTIF()` combination (and, hey, no blank spaces). Hopefully that gets you what you need.

([Reference to using `=INDEX( ,MATCH( , , ))`](http://fiveminutelessons.com/learn-microsoft-excel/how-use-index-match-instead-vlookup))

Comment: The repeated rows are a problem. The example data I gave is minute compared with the rest of my data. I have tried to work with the code you have recommended but I haven't got anywhere with trying to solve this. Thank you for your reply though.

Comment: I know that you had mentioned that you wanted to find a way to do this without using VBA, but perhaps that might be the best way for you to go about this. I'm sorry that the info I gave wasn't overly helpful

Comment: It nearly got the answer (well it did) but the repeated rows just ruin it. I don't know VBA so it looks like I'll be stealing bits of code from different corners of the internet haha, thanks for your help